# Paper Trail Gem: Tracking user activity to give reputation points

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a question about the gem called [Paper Trail](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail). I want to give reputation points to the ones who are the most active on the website. Can this gem help me with this? Also, Is it possible to track which users edited or created a model that doesn't belong to them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any time a change is made in your system, paper trail can track the user id via a `whodunnit` property. This is set automatically if your controller makes a `current_user` object available. I know [authlogic](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic) does this and I bet [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) does too. so yes, it will track any user, regardless of whether there is an actual relationship between the user and the model.